# c# - Generic interfaces types

Tags: c#, generics

i've made a mini project to get with reflection all the interfaces from the dll i've imported, that inherits from my "IBase" interface like this

```
 Type[] services = typeof(DataAccess.IXXX).Assembly.GetTypes();
 foreach (Type SC in services)
        {
            if (SC.IsInterface)
            {
                if (SC.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(DataAccess.IBase)))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(SC.Name);
                }
             }
         }
```

The problem is that a lot of my interfaces contains generics

```
public interface IExample<TKey, Tvalue, TCount> : IBase
```

But my SC.Name write that like this

```
IExample'3
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IExample'3` is the internal name of the of an interface with 3 generic type arguments (as you have probably already guessed). To get the generic type arguments of a class or interface use the [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use something like this to print the correct name

```
var type = typeof(IExample<int, double>);
var arguments = Type.GetGenericArguments(type);
if(arguments.Any())
{
    var name = argument.Name.Replace("'" + arguments.Length, "");
    Console.Write(name + "<");
    Console.Write(string.Join(", ", arguments.Select(x => x.Name));     
    Console.WriteLine(">")
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
}
```

Comment: seems you forget second parameter for `.Name.Replace`. And bit improvement: instead `foreach loop` i think better use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx): `string.Join(", ", arguments.Select(a=>a.Name))`

Comment: @Grundy, you're right. I typed this code from memory. I've updated it now with your suggestions.

Comment: and again bit improvement:-) `Console.WriteLine` avail format, so it can be like this: `Console.WriteLine("{0}<{1}>",argument.Name.Replace("'" + arguments.Length, ""), string.Join(", ", arguments.Select(x => x.Name))`

Answer (score 2):

I think [Type.GetGenericArguments Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the .NET name property doesn't show you the generic parameter types as part of the name.  You have to get the parameter types from GetGenericArguments.

Here is a method returns the name of a generic type in the C# style.  It is recursive, so it can handle generics that have generic types as parameters i.e `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, int>>`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static string FancyTypeName(Type type)
{
    var typeName = type.Name.Split('`')[0];
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        typeName += string.Format("<{0}>", string.Join(",", type.GetGenericArguments().Select(v => FancyTypeName(v)).ToArray()));
    }
    return typeName;
}
```

Comment: Good call that the types in a generic type can also be generic!

Comment: Thanks.  I ran into this on a project a while back and I just had to find the code.